# Why Multiple Submits javascript code is not working wtih Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve a stress test on my Web Application with the help of the below code.

I observed that the same code below is working to some extent in  Firefox (but not great), but not at all working with Chrome.

The version of chrome I am using is  Version 28.0.1500.95 m

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
var myStringArray = ["erer", "rerere"]
var len = myStringArray.length;
var windowCounter = 1; // make sure you declare this globally
for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
setTimeout(function() {
document.inform.target = windowCounter++; // a different target each time
document.inform.cid.value=myStringArray[0];
document.inform.pw.value="xxxxxxxx";
document.inform.submit();
}, i*10000); // change 1000 to the interval you need in milliseconds
}
}
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="inform" method="post"  target="newWin" action="http://10.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/logon">
  <input type="text" name="cid" >
 <input type="password" name="pw" />
<input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="test()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: My guess: Pop Up Blocker or it is ignoring your numeric target.

Comment: @j08691 here not working means , the browser simply didn't open any tabs for me. , hey you cn try by replacing my localhost site with some google.com

Comment: If you want the form submission to open a new tab, use `target="_blank"`, not `target="newWin"`.

Answer (score 1):

Non-ajax form submissions trigger a full page load, so you can't rely on any JavaScript executing after that point. Use ajax to submit the form instead.